# Centering a div on the page

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla3.0

i am creating a Joomla website which uses a template based on EF4 framework. There, i have set the main content width to 1170 px.
What i want to achieve is to make a div containing an  and a

on the homepage centered.
Howhever, when i apply the following code, it won't get perfectly centered, as you can see from the attached screenshot (the distance between the beginning of the gallery above the text and the text itself - on the left-, and the distance between the end of the gallery and the end of the text -on the right- aren't the same)
Here's the code:

```
.home-text {
    width: 71%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

and here's the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ0Vt.jpg)

Any clues? thanks for your attention

Comment: still nothing? i have no clues how to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

Choose that specific div and add like this..

```html
<div align="center">

</div>
```

Also try with css as `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the text? It looks like it.

But: [the text is centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npx5b.jpg).

The circles above aren't.

Answer (score -2):

Choose that specific div and add like this..

```html
<div align="center">

</div>
```

Comment: `align="center"` deprecated for HTML5. The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Please remove the duplicate answers. So that is will not get confuse.[GoodAnswer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)